# Partial isometry which is not quasinormal

Tags: operator-theory

Could you please give me an example of an operator which is partial isometry but not quasinormal ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ with standard orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.  Let $u$ be the partial isometry defined by $ue_1=0$, and $ue_n=e_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 2$. Then we have
$$u^*uue_2=0\neq e_1=ue_2=uu^*ue_2$$
so $uu^*u\neq u^*uu$.

Comment: Thank you @Aweygan for your answer !

Comment: No problem, glad to help!